# How to Unzip a file and copy it to specific location with 7zip?

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I just tried to open a zip archive in powershell and move the files in it to a specific location. but it always moves just the zip folder. What am I doing wrong ?

This is what I have now :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\zipplayground\*.zip | % {"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7zG.exe";
Move-Item $_ C:\unzipplayground\}
```

Comment: Why does your subject reference not using open source DLLs if your question makes no mention of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the right answer should be something like that:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\zipplayground\*.zip | % {& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x" $_.fullname "-oC:\unzipplayground"}
```

Alroc was almost right, but `$_.fullname` between quotes doesn't work, and he was missing the `-o` parameter for 7z. I'm using `7z.exe` instead of `7zg.exe`, works fine this way.

For reference, the command line help can be found here: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/
Basically, `x` stands for 'eXtract' and `-o` for 'Output directory'

Comment: yes, that's it thanks :) the only difference was my path of the 7zip.

Comment: what does the "-o" do before the path?

Comment: It's the 7z parameter for the output directory. And it has to be "attached" to the path, no space allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Function to acquire path of the 7z.exe

```
function Get-7ZipExecutable
{
    $7zipExecutable = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    return $7zipExecutable
}
```

Function to zip folders where the destination is set to

```
function 7Zip-ZipDirectories
{
    param
    (
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]]$include,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$destination
             )

    $7zipExecutable = Get-7ZipExecutable

     # All folders in the destination path will be zipped in .7z format
     foreach ($directory in $include)
    {
        $arguments = "a","$($destination.FullName)","$($directory.FullName)"
    (& $7zipExecutable $arguments)

        $7ZipExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE

        if ($7ZipExitCode -ne 0)
        {
            $destination.Delete()
            throw "An error occurred while zipping [$directory]. 7Zip Exit Code was [$7ZipExitCode]."
        }
    }

    return $destination
}
```

Function to unzip files

```
function 7Zip-Unzip
{
    param
    (
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$archive,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$destinationDirectory
    )

    $7zipExecutable = Get-7ZipExecutable
    $archivePath = $archive.FullName
    $destinationDirectoryPath = $destinationDirectory.FullName

    (& $7zipExecutable x "$archivePath" -o"$destinationDirectoryPath" -aoa -r)

    $7zipExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
    if ($7zipExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        throw "An error occurred while unzipping [$archivePath] to [$destinationDirectoryPath]. 7Zip Exit Code was [$7zipExitCode]."
    }

    return $destinationDirectory
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nithin K Anil for organising it

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 7Zip to test,but I think it's failing because you aren't telling 7Zip what to operate on, and you're moving your ZIP file to the destination yourself. Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\zipplayground\*.zip | % {invoke-expression "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7zG.exe x $_.FullName c:\unzipplayground\";}
```

Comment: Unexpected token 'x' in expression or statement.  what to  put instead of x ? sorry i am new. thanks

Comment: The `x` is correct, you need that to extract the zipfile. It's a matter of syntax with calling the program from Powershell and I don't have anything to test with at the moment. I think you need to move the quotes around. Try my edit.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer below, "$_.fullname" between quotes cannot work, the parser cannot resolve variable members.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid open source exe/dll like 7zip then install the PSCX module for powershell and use expand-archive.  Note that PSCX requirements are at least .net 4 ( I use 4.5 ) and powershell 3.0

http://pscx.codeplex.com/